# How do I make a through-hole via?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, via, pcb-layers, etching

Using a simple PCB with copper on both sides but naturally in between, is it feasible for a hobbyist to make through-hole vias like this:

[image]

It seems there is copper in the via itself, isn't there?

If it is not easy to do, what would be the best solution? Simply fill the hole with solder? Or should I put a miniature wire or some component's lead to connect the two sides?

Comment: Of course there is copper in the via. Filing it with solder might cause bad connection leading to problem, putting a small wire or lead through with solder would be the simplest solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I have a board like that, I tend to cut off a small section of wire, and solder around that, to try and make a good connection.

This is just what I have done on a few occasions, and may not be best practice.